# Update dealer id in first table where dealer names are equal in first and second tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I has two MS SQL databases with sales and dealer tables. Dealers has the same names in both databases, but has a different ID.
First database DB1.sales table has a dealers id.
I need to update sales table on second database and set dealer ID = dealer ID from second database where dealer names are equal in first and second tables (db1.dbo.Dealer.Name=db2.dbo.dealer.name). Some records in db2.salestable has no dealer ID.

Query give me error:

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression."

```
UPDATE db2.salestable
set salestable.dealer=(select dealer.Id from db2.dbo.dealer
LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.Dealer ON dealer.name=Dealer.Name
where db1.dbo.Dealer.Name=db2.dbo.dealer.name )
```

I think that I need to use 'with' clause, but I don't know how. Subquery returns more then one value and I need to update all records
where db1.dbo.Dealer.Name=db2.dbo.dealer.name

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your subquery returns more then one value. Which one of them do you want? (A similar WITH clause would fail too.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update + joins. Note the result could be unpredictable if `db1.dbo.Dealer` contains `name` dups

```
update s2
   set dealer = d1.Id
from db2.salestable s2
join db2.dbo.dealer d2 on s2.dealer = d2.Id
join db1.dbo.Dealer d1 on d1.name = d2.name
```

Comment: Update work if db2.salestable.dealer has ID. But I need to update that are haven't ID

Comment: If you have neither name nor id referencing a source how would you choose an appropriate row from the source? If an arbitrary one will do just `select top(1) ..` in your subquery.